# Scala defaulting typed list to be of type String

Tags: scala, collections

Scala 2.12 here. I have the following classes:

```
abstract class AbstractCollector {
  def name() : String
  def collect() : Map[String,AnyVal]
}

class NativeSystemCollector(sysInfo : SystemInfo) extends AbstractCollector {
  override def name(): String = "NativeSystem"

  override def collect(): Map[String, AnyVal] = ???
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a "provider" method that returns a `List[AbstractCollectors]`:

```
def nativeSystemCollector() : NativeSystemCollector = new NativeSystemCollector(systemInfo())

def collectors() : List[AbstractCollector] = {
  var collectors = List[AbstractCollector]()

  collectors += nativeSystemCollector()

  collectors
}
```

This code gives me a compiler error at `collectors += nativeSystemCollector()`:

> "*Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: NativeSystemCollector*"

**Any ideas as to why the compiler thinks `collectors` is a list of Strings when I clearly declare it as a new list of `AbstractCollectors`?!?**

Comment: Might be worth renaming either the def or the var so you know which `collectors` it is referring to. **Edit:** I am aware that it is referring to the var, but it's not a great idea to have multiple things with the same name. It makes your code unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ListBuffer` over `List` when dealing with mutable lists. For example:

```
def collectors() : List[AbstractCollector] = {
  var collectorList: ListBuffer[AbstractCollector] = ListBuffer[AbstractCollector]()

  collectorList += nativeSystemCollector()

  collectorList.toList
}
```

If you really want to use a `List`, use the `:+` symbol:

```
def collectors() : List[AbstractCollector] = {
  val collectorList: List[AbstractCollector] = List[AbstractCollector]()

  collectorList :+ nativeSystemCollector()
}
```

Looking at `+=`, it is constructed like this:

```
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
}
```

Since List[AbstractCollector] doesn't have a `+=` method, I think it assumes you are dealing with Strings and falls over.

Read more [here](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-add-elements-to-a-list-in-scala-listbuffer-immutable) about adding to Lists.

Answer (score 3):

It does not think that `collectors` is a `List[String]`.

Instead, it notices that `collectors` is immutable and does not have `+=` method. So it tries to desugar

```
collectors += nativeSystemCollector()
```

into

```
collectors = collectors + nativeSystemCollector()
```

and then doesn't know what the `+` is supposed to mean. Since there is no `+` method on `List`, it implicitly converts `collectors` into a `String`, but then notices that `nativeSystemCollector()` is not another `String`, and gives up.

If you want to construct a list by appending elements, use a mutable `ListBuffer` instead:

```
val collectors = collection.mutable.ListBuffer[AbstractCollector]()

collectors += nativeSystemCollector()

collectors.toList
```

Appending to a `List` is expensive anyway.